# How to prevent PHP scripts from displaying credentials or other crucial data when there is an error?

Tags: exception, pdo

I am trying to handle exceptions or errors in a way that they do not end up blurting out any important details regarding my application. I would like to know of the best approach followed to prevent such a thing. From the snippet below do you think it would prevent the credentials from being dumped onto the screen?

```
public static function exception_handler($exception) 
{
    die('Uncaught exception: '.$exception->getMessage());
}

public function __construct() 
{
    $this->host     = 'xxxxx';
    $this->dbname   = 'xxxxx';
    $this->dsn      = "host";
    $this->username = 'xxxx';
    $this->password = 'xxxx';
    $this->opt      = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    set_exception_handler(array(__CLASS__, 'exception_handler'));
    parent::__construct($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, $this->opt);
    restore_exception_handler();
}
```

Comment: catch the error, log it to disk, and then output a generic error message to the user. When they report the error, the support person can check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would but it scarcely would help as the **error message itself would leak as well.**

Besides, setting an error handler for just single line makes no sense. There are A LOT of classes in your app, with A LOT of credentials and sensitive information. So you can tell that you'd rather prevent any leakage - not the only  one you've accidentally got aware of.

So leave your database class alone

```
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->host     = 'xxxxx';
    $this->dbname   = 'xxxxx';
    $this->dsn      = "host";
    $this->username = 'xxxx';
    $this->password = 'xxxx';
    $this->opt      = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    parent::__construct($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, $this->opt);
}
```

(though, better yet leave alone PDO itself, as your class most likely contracted some of [childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)).

While a site-wide handler should be like this

```
set_exception_handler('exception_handler'));
public static function exception_handler($exception) 
{
    error_log("[$errno] $errstr in $errfile:$errline");
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    die('Server error');
}
```